# Difference between np.int, np.int_, int, and np.int_t in cython?

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I am a bit struggled with so many `int` data types in cython.

`np.int, np.int_, np.int_t, int`

I guess `int` in pure python is equivalent to `np.int_`, then where does `np.int` come from? I cannot find the document from numpy? Also, why does `np.int_` exist given we do already have `int`?

In cython, I guess `int` becomes a C type when used as `cdef int` or `ndarray[int]`, and when used as `int()` it stays as the python caster?

Is `np.int_` equivalent to `long` in C? so `cdef long` is the identical to `cdef np.int_`?

Under what circumstances should I use `np.int_t` instead of `np.int`? e.g. `cdef np.int_t`, `ndarray[np.int_t]` ...

Can someone briefly explain how the wrong use of those types would affect the performance of compiled cython code?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/wiki/C-integer-types%3A-the-missing-manual

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's a bit complicated because the names have different meanings depending on the context.

## `int`

1. In Python

   The `int` is normally just a Python type, it's of arbitrary precision, meaning that you can store any conceivable integer inside it (as long as you have enough memory).

   ```
   >>> int(10**50)
   100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   ```
2. However, when you use it as `dtype` for a NumPy array it will be interpreted as `np.int_` <sup>1</sup>. Which is **not** of arbitrary precision, it will have the same size as C's `long`:

   ```
   >>> np.array(10**50, dtype=int)
   OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
   ```

   That also means the following two are equivalent:

   ```
   np.array([1,2,3], dtype=int)
   np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int_)
   ```
3. As Cython type identifier it has another meaning, here it stands for the [c](/questions/tagged/c) type `int`. It's of limited precision (typically 32bits). You can use it as Cython type, for example when defining variables with `cdef`:

   ```
   cdef int value = 100    # variable
   cdef int[:] arr = ...   # memoryview
   ```

   As return value or argument value for `cdef` or `cpdef` functions:

   ```
   cdef int my_function(int argument1, int argument2):
       # ...
   ```

   As "generic" for `ndarray`:

   ```
   cimport numpy as cnp
   cdef cnp.ndarray[int, ndim=1] val = ...
   ```

   For type casting:

   ```
   avalue = <int>(another_value)
   ```

   And probably many more.
4. In Cython but as Python type. You can still call `int` and you'll get a "Python int" (of arbitrary precision), or use it for `isinstance` or as `dtype` argument for `np.array`. Here the context is important, so converting to a Python `int` is different from converting to a C int:

   ```
   cdef object val = int(10)  # Python int
   cdef int val = <int>(10)   # C int
   ```

## `np.int`

Actually this is very easy. It's just an alias for `int`:

```
>>> int is np.int
True
```

So everything from above applies to `np.int` as well. However you can't use it as a type-identifier except when you use it on the `cimport`ed package. In that case it represents the Python integer type.

```
cimport numpy as cnp

cpdef func(cnp.int obj):
    return obj
```

This will expect `obj` to be a Python integer **not a NumPy type**:

```
>>> func(np.int_(10))
TypeError: Argument 'obj' has incorrect type (expected int, got numpy.int32)
>>> func(10)
10
```

My advise regarding `np.int`: Avoid it whenever possible. In Python code it's equivalent to `int` and in Cython code it's also equivalent to Pythons `int` but if used as type-identifier it will probably confuse you and everyone who reads the code! It certainly confused me...

## `np.int_`

Actually it only has one meaning: It's a **Python type** that represents a scalar NumPy type. You use it like Pythons `int`:

```
>>> np.int_(10)        # looks like a normal Python integer
10
>>> type(np.int_(10))  # but isn't (output may vary depending on your system!)
numpy.int32
```

Or you use it to specify the `dtype`, for example with `np.array`:

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int_)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

But you cannot use it as type-identifier in Cython.

## `cnp.int_t`

It's the type-identifier version for `np.int_`. That means you can't use it as dtype argument. But you can use it as type for `cdef` declarations:

```
cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np

cdef cnp.int_t[:] arr = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int_)
     |---TYPE---|                         |---DTYPE---|
```

This example (hopefully) shows that the type-identifier with the trailing `_t` actually represents the type of an array using the **dtype** without the trailing `t`. You can't interchange them in Cython code!

## Notes

There are several more numeric types in NumPy I'll include a list containing the NumPy dtype and Cython type-identifier and the C type identifier that could also be used in Cython here. But it's basically taken from [the NumPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#array-types-and-conversions-between-types) and the [Cython NumPy `pxd` file](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd):

```
NumPy dtype          Numpy Cython type         C Cython type identifier

np.bool_             None                      None
np.int_              cnp.int_t                 long
np.intc              None                      int       
np.intp              cnp.intp_t                ssize_t
np.int8              cnp.int8_t                signed char
np.int16             cnp.int16_t               signed short
np.int32             cnp.int32_t               signed int
np.int64             cnp.int64_t               signed long long
np.uint8             cnp.uint8_t               unsigned char
np.uint16            cnp.uint16_t              unsigned short
np.uint32            cnp.uint32_t              unsigned int
np.uint64            cnp.uint64_t              unsigned long
np.float_            cnp.float64_t             double
np.float32           cnp.float32_t             float
np.float64           cnp.float64_t             double
np.complex_          cnp.complex128_t          double complex
np.complex64         cnp.complex64_t           float complex
np.complex128        cnp.complex128_t          double complex
```

Actually there are Cython types for `np.bool_`: `cnp.npy_bool` and `bint` but both  they can't be used for NumPy arrays currently. For scalars `cnp.npy_bool` will just be an unsigned integer while `bint` will be a boolean. Not sure what's going on there...

---

<sup>1</sup> Taken From the [NumPy documentation "Data type objects"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types)

> ### Built-in Python types
>
> Several python types are equivalent to a corresponding array scalar when used to generate a dtype object:
>
> ```
> int           np.int_
> bool          np.bool_
> float         np.float_
> complex       np.cfloat
> bytes         np.bytes_
> str           np.bytes_ (Python2) or np.unicode_ (Python3)
> unicode       np.unicode_
> buffer        np.void
> (all others)  np.object_
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very thorough overview!

Comment: What about `np.integer`?

Comment: @HebertoMayorquin it's an abstract base class that exists to check (using `isinstance` or `issubclass`) if you have any integer dtype (comparably to `collections.abc.Hashable` and similar). Since it's not a "real" dtype and it's (as far as I know) not specially implemented in Cython it's not really relevant for this question. But feel free to ask a new question if you want to know something specific.

Comment: @MSeifert thanks, that was it. I guess that the fact that the dtypes have similar names to the abstract classes for the objects confused me.
This came from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72549583/type-hints-for-both-integer-and-elements-of-numpy-integer-arrays-in-python

Comment: The matched C type is platform dependent so that chart is _very_ misleading.

Answer (score 8):

`np.int_` is the default integer type ([as defined in the NumPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#id3)), on a 64bit system this would be a `C long`. `np.intc` is the default `C int` either `int32` or `int64`. `np.int` is an alias to the built-in `int` function

```
>>> np.int(2.4)
2
>>> np.int is int  # object id equality
True
```

The cython datatypes should reflect `C` datatypes, so `cdef int a` is a `C int` and so on.

As for `np.int_t` that is the `Cython` compile time equivalent of the NumPy `np.int_` datatype, `np.int64_t` is the `Cython` compile time equivalent of `np.int64`

Comment: `np.intc` is practically always 32 bits. I've never seen a C environment where `int` is 64 bits.

Comment: Can I always use `np.int_t` instead of `np.int_` under cython `cdef`, or vice vesa?

Comment: You can't use when instantiating numpy arrays `np.zeros(5, 5, dtype=np.int_t)` will throw an error where as `np.zeros(5, 5, dtype=np.int_)` won't. You can use it to declare the type of the array though `np.ndarray[np.int_t] a = ...` and since it's a compile time thing you'll get early warnings anyway.

Comment: Then, can I always use `np.int_`  instead of `np.int_t`? Do I suffer any speed loss?

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but speed loss should be negligible. The only difference would be that `np.int_` may (or may not) take more than 4 bytes, while `np.int_t` is guaranteed 4 bytes.

Comment: @richizy you can't use `np.int_` in a cdef type declaration because it is not a compile time datatype `cdef np.int_ a = 1` throws an error. You have to use `np.int_t`. You can take `np.int_` in as a variable (without declaring the type) and use it, but it'll have to go through some Python code to figure out the runtime datatype. Compile a file with `cython -a` and check the html output, all the yellow lines have Python on them and will suffer in terms of speed, inside loops you don't want to have any yellow lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clarification on difference between `int` and `np.int_t` in Cython code, which are not the same:

**`np.int_t` maps to `long` and not to `int` in Cython code.**

That means:

- On 64bit Windows (i.e. compiled with MSVC), `int` is 4 bytes but also `long` (and thus `np.int_t`).
- On 64bit Linux (i.e. compiled with gcc), `int` is 4 bytes but `long` (and thus `np.int_t`) is 8 bytes!

An `np.int`-numpy-array would map to `np.int_t[:]`-memory view in Cython, which is correct because the following code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(1, np.int_)  # or np.zeros(1, np.int)
print(a.itemsize)
```

would yield `4` (size of `long` in bytes on Windows) on Windows and `8` on Linux.

Often it makes sense to specify exactly how big the values are, e.g. by using `np.int32` and `np.int64` which would map to `np.int32_t` and `np.int64_t` in Cython and have the same size on all platforms.