# Why does the data type `intc` in numpy default to 32 bits?

Tags: python, numpy

Why does the data type `intc` in numpy default to 32 bits when running 32-bit Anaconda with Python 2.7 on a 64-bit OS?

Example:

```
np.intc(1).dtype
#  dtype('int32')
```

Similarly:

```
type(np.intc(1))
#  <type 'numpy.int32'>
```

However:

```
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
sysinfo.platform_bits
#  64
```

And similarly:

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
#  ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

OS:

```
Windows 10 Enterprise
```

Anaconda:

```
conda version : 4.4.10
conda-build version : 3.4.1
python version : 2.7.14.final.0
channel URLs :        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
platform : win-64
```

Comment: What would you expect `intc` to be when running a 32-bit version of Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.intc` is defined as an integer with the size of `int` in C in the compiler used to build the runtime ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21853920/1782792)). In most modern compilers, even in 64-bit toolchains, `int` is defined to be 32 bits ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes)). In your case you are using a 32-bit compilation of Python, the chances of a compiler producing 32-bit binaries having `int` defined as anything else than 32 are quite low.

You can check the size of `int` in one particular compiler with a program like the following:

```c
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("int size: %d bits.\n", sizeof(int) * 8);
    return 0;
}
```

You will see that most compilers will produce a program showing:

```
int size: 32 bits.
```