# pandas apply convert to int differences between np.int, lambda and astype()

Tags: python, pandas

Given a df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['0', '1', '2', '3'], columns=['a'])
```

What is the difference between using

```
 df['b'] = df['a'].apply(np.int)
```

,

```
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x : int(x))
```

and

```
df['b'] = df['a'].astype(int)
```

?

I'm aware that all will give the same result but are there any differences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between np.int, np.int\_, int, and np.int\_t in cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851985/difference-between-np-int-np-int-int-and-np-int-t-in-cython)

Answer (score 0):

np.int is an alias for int.

You can test this by running:

```
import numpy as np
print(int == np.int)
```

which will return True.

Also: consider checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851985/difference-between-np-int-np-int-int-and-np-int-t-in-cython) which has a very thorough explanation of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The below uses pandas apply function to iteratively use numpy's *int* cast which is same as python's *int* cast. So, both of these are alas the same.

```
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(np.int)
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x : int(x))
```

The astype function however casts an series to specified dtype, here *int* which for pandas is *int64*.

```
df['b'] = df['a'].astype(int)
```

*astype* is a vectorized function and I would prefer to use it rather than the *apply* method due to its poor time complexity as compared to *astype*.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `apply` it works by looping over the data and changing the dtype of each value to integer. So they are slower when compared to `astype`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(10**7).reshape(10**4, 10**3)).astype(str)

# Performance
%timeit df[0].apply(np.int)
7.15 ms ± 319 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df[0].apply(lambda x : int(x))
9.57 ms ± 405 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Both are almost similar in terms of performance.

Here `astype` which is function optimized to work faster than apply.

```
%timeit df[0].astype(int)
1.94 ms ± 96.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And If you are looking for a much much faster approach then we should opt for vectorized approach which ***numpy*** arrays can provide.

```
%timeit df[0].values.astype(np.int)
1.26 ms ± 19.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

As you can see the time difference is huge.