# Difference between dtype = np.int and int when creating array

Tags: python, numpy, integer, dtype

I am confused with the difference between integer types.

For example, here is a `numpy.array` with dtype of `np.int`.

```
>>> arr_ = np.array([1,2], dtype = np.int)
```

Through the below code, it represents **true** that `int` is the same as `np.int`:

```
>>> int is np.int
Out[1]: True
```

However, when I select the first value of the array which is created with dtype of `np.int`, the below code outputs **false**.

```
>>> type(arr_[0]) is int
Out[2]: False
```

Why does the code output **false**, not **true**?

It seems like that `dtype = np.int` dose not applied on the `arr_`.

Why `np.int` dose not applied as a dtype on the array?

I've looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851985/difference-between-np-int-np-int-int-and-np-int-t-in-cython), but couldn't get what I need.

Comment: Could you add what value `type(arr_[0])` returns?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh It returns `numpy.int32`, even I set a dtype `np.int`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. The question you linked describes how `int` (or `np.int` which is another name for the same type) get converted to `np.int_` when used as an array's `dtype`. That explains the behavior you're seeing exactly. What more do you need to know?

Comment: The thing you pass as `dtype` is usually not going to be the type object of elements retrieved from the array. After all, you can do `dtype='int32'`, and the string `'int32'` can't be `type(anything)`.

Comment: display `type(arr_[0])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python the types `int`, `np.int32` and `np.int64` are 3 different types:

- `int` is the native Python multiprecision integer type able to represent any integer value (the only limit being available memory). For example `2**128` is a valid `int` value
- `np.int32` in the `int32_t` C integer type that can represent values using up to 32 bits, that is values between -2147483648 and 2147483647
- `np.int64` is the `int64_t` C integer type that can represent values using up to 64 bits, that is values between -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807

And `np.int` is a (deprecated alias) for the native Python `int` type, the reason why `int is np.int` is true. But numpy integer arrays even with `dtype=int` receive an actual type of `np.int32` or `np.int64` because they have to be processed by C code so they have to by coerced to a fixed size integer type. If you really need to store true `int` values, you will have to use `dtype=object` but operations will no longer be vectorizable.

Comment: Note that none of these are an actual dtype. dtypes are represented by `numpy.dtype` objects rather than by Python types, because dtypes and types represent different things. A dtype's job is to represent stuff like endianness and structured array padding and other memory layout information, while a Python type object's job is to represent information about inheritance hierarchies and how to dispatch methods and operators.

Comment: `numpy.int32` and `numpy.int64` are the types Numpy uses for [array scalars](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html) of int32 and int64 dtype.